# wp_sanitize_redirect strips out @ signs (even from parameters) -- why?

Tags: url-rewriting, wp-redirect, sanitization

In my Wordpress site I have a hack that looks at the uri and does a redirect to a subdomain. The problem is `wp_redirect` calls `wp_sanitize_redirect` which will strip out `@` signs, so when a user tries to load something like

```
oursite.com?email=foo@bar.com
```

The page that gets loaded should be

```
prefix.oursite.com?email=foo@bar.com
```

but instead it's

```
prefix.oursite.com?email=foobar.com (i.e. - no @ sign)
```

The problem is easy to work around - I just manually encode @ signs as %40 before calling `wp_redirect`.

Question: why does `wp_sanitize_redirect` strip out `@` signs, exactly? Anybody could anyway try to load a url with an `@` sign in it - is there some security issue I'm not thinking about?

EDIT: The function I'm talking about is [`wp_sanitize_redirect`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_sanitize_redirect)

Comment: I've never seen a function called `wp_sanitize_url()`. Could you please point to the core file, where it is defined? Thanks.

Comment: My bad, I mean wp_sanitize_redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Question** why does `wp_sanitize_redirect` strip out `@` signs, exactly? Anybody could anyway try to load a url with an `@` sign in it - is there some security issue I'm not thinking about?

Just take a look at the source:

```
function wp_sanitize_redirect($location) {
    $location = preg_replace('|[^a-z0-9-~+_.?#=&;,/:%!]|i', '', $location);
    $location = wp_kses_no_null($location);

    // remove %0d and %0a from location
    $strip = array('%0d', '%0a', '%0D', '%0A');
    $location = _deep_replace($strip, $location);
    return $location;
}
```

So the only characters, the `preg_replace` allows are

- lower case `a-z`
- numbers
- and `~+_.?#=&;,/:%!`.

### What does that mean for URIs and URLs?

The php function `urlencode()` replaces **all** no alpha-numeric chararcters, **except** `-_.` with a `%` (percent) character followed by two hexdecimal values and spaces with a `+`. If you use `rawurlencode()`, it also strips the `+`. As you can see from the `preg_replace()`, it allows all URL encoded/prepared characters, so it's safe to throw such encoded characters/URL parts into the game.

Comment: Right, I see what the regexp is doing, I was wondering why. I mean, why does it not url encode characters rather than strip them out? And is it safe to just url encode @ signs as %40 and then call wp_redirect? Maybe this was a silly question.

Comment: Yes, it works - see edit.

Comment: Well I know it *works*, I mean... oh, never mind. Accepted. Thanks for the trouble.

Comment: In my case I wanted `|` is the URL and it is being stripped. It is a valid character and required by `GTranslate`. Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to follow up on my own findings.  This happened to me if I was leaving out the last / in my URLs.  Doing so caused WP to call func:redirect_canonical which stripped out the @ symbols.  When I added the last / it did not call this function and the @ symbol remained.

A good plugin for debugging redirects is: Debug WP Redirect

**Example 1 which fails:**

Original URL: www.domain.com/somepage?email=me@me.com

Final URL   : www.domain.com/somepage/?email=meme.com

**Example 2 which works:**

Original URL: www.domain.com/somepage/?email=me@me.com

Final URL   : www.domain.com/somepage/?email=me@me.com

Comment: Is this an actual answer that helps the OP to solve the problem?