# Overiding wp_sanitize_redirect for | character

Tags: wp-redirect

I am not really conversant with php and I have an issue with `wp_sanitize_redirect`. I have seen this excellent question and answer:

[wp_sanitize_redirect strips out @ signs (even from parameters) -- why?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/64818/wp-sanitize-redirect-strips-out-signs-even-from-parameters-why)

How do I override this method Wordpress so that I can pass the `|` as part of a URL and it not get stripped out?

I am using the latest 5.x edition of Wordpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was another solution. I looked here:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

And it stated the encoded value for a `|` character was `%7C` so I was able to use that in my redirection URLs.